# C++ allocating an array of pointers to struct

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

I am writing a program which needs to have an array of pointers to a `struct SMesh`, specifically

```
SMesh **mesh_arr;
```

When I work with an instance that has only one pointer in the array, everything is OK. But when I try to work with instance that has got two (or more) of them, Valgrind goes crazy with `"Invalid write of size..."`.
I initialize it like this (with counter being the number of SMeshes that I need pointers to) :

```
SMesh **mesh_arr = new SMesh*;
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) mesh_arr[i] = new SMesh;
```

And delete it like this :

```
delete mesh_arr;
```

Do I delete it the wrong way or have I missed something?

Comment: Do you mean a pointer to a pointer __**ptr__

Comment: 'new' and 'delete' generate errors in my C compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to allocate enough elements to have the entire array, not only 1 element.

```
SMesh **mesh_arr = new SMesh*[counter];
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) mesh_arr[i] = new SMesh;
```

Using `new[]`, you have to use `delete[]` to delete it.

```
delete[] mesh_arr;
```

Also don't forget to delete the individual `SMesh`s allocated.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid pointer trouble with a vector. No need to explicitly delete either.

```
#include <vector>

auto mesharr{std::vector<std::vector<SMesh>>(rows, std::vector<SMesh>(cols))};
```

Answer (score -1):

You have only allocated one pointer to your structure in your `new` statement. Try

```
SMesh ** mesh_arr = new (SMesh*)[counter];
```